# Stop creation of .bak file

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, process, backup

I back up database in .bak file:

```
BACKUP DATABASE MyDatabase TO DISK='E:\MyDatabase.bak'
```

How can I stop this process?

Comment: if you are talking about,how to close the current backup you triggered,just kill the session

Answer (score 0):

You can stop a running backup by using the `kill YourProcessIDHere` command.

To identify the process to kill use `sp_who` command and look in the cmd column for backup command.

More information can be found here:  [MSDN Kill](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173730.aspx)

Comment: I haven't session ID.
User clicks on button "Stop backup" and I must stop creation of .back file

Comment: @Kirill see my updated answer.  You are looking for a spid ( commonly known as sql process id ).  with the SPID obtained by using sp_who you can kill the spid executing the backup command.